# Webservice register "created_by" user

Tags: php, database, rest, web-services, yii2

in the following scenario 2 Apps App A (main) and App B which will register in the "work_list" table of App A via a webservice.

The table "work_list" has a foreign key "created_by" which is the primary key in the users table and which saves the login of the user who registered.

The users registered in the "users" table will necessarily be different, not having the same user registered in both APPS.

Through APP B I will make a record in the table "work_list" using a webservice. So how do I save user "created_by" from APP B, in APP A to know who made a registration? Since for example APP 1 user id 1 is different from APP B. user id 1

In principle a single user table scenario will not be possible in the project.[image]

Comment: I cannot really understand what you are looking for. Please, be more specific in the question.

Comment: @Martin Dimitrov sorry my english, i update the question..

Answer (score 0):

If there will be duplicates in `a_users` and `b_users`, I would suggest change the `create_by` column to work with strings instead of integers. Then you can fill the `created_by` with a string in the format `table + id`(example `a1`, which would mean that user with `id == 1` from table `A_users` has created this record or `b2` -> user with `id == 2` from table `B_users`). Then you can parse this `created_by` field in the respective places in both applications.